# Recursive looping through files stops abruptly

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow, callstack

So I'm trying to run through every file on my harddrive, but it stops once it gets to the 2115th (I think) loop. I believe it is a stack overflow due to my use of recursion, but I'm new to C# and really have no idea. Here's my code, thank you very much.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace test_data
{
    class Program
    {
        static string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

        static void CrawlDir(string dir)
        {
            string[] dir_package = {};
            List<string> dir_list = new List<string>();
            foreach (string scan_dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {

                try
                {
                    dir_list.Add(scan_dir);
                }
                catch (System.Exception error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                }

            }

            dir_package = dir_list.ToArray();
            Process_Package(dir_package);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CrawlDir(drive);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Process_Package(string[] package)
        {
            foreach (string dir in package)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir);
                try
                {
                    CrawlDir(dir);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You might be getting an Access Denied error on one of the subdirectories you're trying to access.  Try looking at the exception in your Catch statement in the Process_Package method to see what the actual error is if that's where the error is occurring.

Comment: @Time Schmelter: Nope, the recursion halts as soon as Directory.GetDirectories() returns no results.

Answer (score 2):

Just use what's built in - `Directory.GetDirectories` supports an optional parameter to specify if you want to get all directories recursively:

```
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(drive, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Note that this is a blocking call - instead you could use `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` to receive the directory names one by one as they are being found:

```
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(drive, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(string dir in dirs)
{
   Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx) with [SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx) so you don't have to do any recursion:

```
public static string[] GetDirectories(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion looks more or less ok, although you do not really need a list in CrawlDir. If you had a stack overflow you'd get a nasty message.

My guess is - the program completes and stops at ReadLine() waiting for you to press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a lot of overhead to each level of recursion by using a List (dir_list), an array (dir_package) and two try/catch loops.  I don't know what you're really trying to do, but for this example it's way overkill.

Still, it would take a lot to cause a stack overflow on a modern OS.  What error message are you getting?

This code should be equivalent.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace test_data
{
    class Program
    {
        static string drive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

        static void CrawlDir(string dir)
        {
            foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(subDir);
                    CrawlDir(subDir);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CrawlDir(drive);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys. I'm just making this as a test exercise.